# Direct initialization != copy initialization when converting from different type?

Tags: c++, packaged-task, copy-initialization, direct-initialization

I always thought direct initialization and copy initialization for types T that do not match the class type are absolutely equal. Yet I seem to be mistaken. The following code doesn't compile if I copy initialize (using = ) and only compiles when I do direct initialization via paranthesis () (in any case the code doesn't *work* as it terminates, but that's a different story and not relevant for this question).

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:10,endLineNumber:10,positionColumn:10,positionLineNumber:10,selectionStartColumn:10,selectionStartLineNumber:10,startColumn:10,startLineNumber:10),source:%27%23include+%3Cfuture%3E%0A%23include+%3Ccstdio%3E%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++/*+This+doesn!%27t+compile+*/%0A%0A++++//+std::packaged_task%3Cint()%3E+foo+%3D+%5B%5D()+-%3E+int+%7B%0A++++//+++++return+10%3B%0A++++//+%7D%3B%0A%0A++++/*+This+works+*/%0A%0A++++std::packaged_task%3Cint()%3E+foo(%5B%5D()+-%3E+int+%7B%0A++++++++return+10%3B%0A++++%7D)%3B%0A%0A++++auto+fut+%3D+foo.get_future()%3B%0A++++foo()%3B%0A++++auto+a+%3D+fut.get()%3B%0A++++printf(%22a+%3D%3D+%25d%5Cn%22,+a)%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:57.59791122715404,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:gsnapshot,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-Wall+-Os+--std%3Dc%2B%2B20%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:41.3677130044843,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+12.2%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:58.632286995515706,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:42.40208877284596,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

```
#include <future>
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
    /* This doesn't compile */

    // std::packaged_task<int()> foo = []() -> int {
    //     return 10;
    // };

    /* This works */

    std::packaged_task<int()> foo([]() -> int {
        return 10;
    });

    auto fut = foo.get_future();
    foo();
    auto a = fut.get();
    printf("a == %d\n", a);
}
```

Error:

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:8:37: error: conversion from 'main()::<lambda()>' to non-scalar type 'std::packaged_task<int()>' requested
    8 |     std::packaged_task<int()> foo = []() -> int {
      |                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
    9 |         return 10;
      |         ~~~~~~~~~~                   
   10 |     };
      |     ~
```

[cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization) states the following for copy-initialization:

For case T = U:

> Otherwise, if T is a class type, and the cv-unqualified version of the
> type of other is not T or derived from T, or if T is non-class type,
> but the type of other is a class type, **user-defined conversion
> sequences** that can convert from the type of other to T (or to a type
> derived from T if T is a class type and a conversion function is
> available) are examined and the best one is selected through overload
> resolution. The result of the conversion, which is a rvalue temporary
> (until C++11)prvalue temporary (since C++11)(until C++17)prvalue
> expression (since C++17) of the cv-unqualified version of T if a
> converting constructor was used, is then used to direct-initialize the
> object. The last step is usually optimized out and the result of the
> conversion is constructed directly in the memory allocated for the
> target object, but the appropriate constructor (move or copy) is
> required to be accessible even though it's not used. (until C++17)

As stated here I would expect that the constructor of `std::package_task`, which takes basically the same invocables as `std::function`, would make a conversion sequence available in that a lambda can be converted to `std::packaged_task`, such as is the case for direct initialization. But this doesn't seem to happen. What am I overlooking?

Comment: I see no [assignment](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/packaged_task/operator%3D) overload for a callable on the right hand site. And callables are not implicitly convertible to packaged tasks since all [constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/packaged_task/packaged_task) accepting a callable are explicit.

Comment: The packaged_task will however accept any type via universal reference constructor: template <class F> explicit packaged_task( F&& f ); Why does it not accept a lambda then, even if it is explicit?

Comment: AFIAK template functions are not considered when type conversions come into play. Your right hand side will first need to be converted to a packaged task, before the template is considered

Comment: @PepijnKramer not sure but I think you refer to conversions not being considered for template argument deduction. Though, thats not relevant here, no conversion is necessary for deduction as `T` matches any type, it also matches the type of the lambda

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is due the [constructor of `std::packaged_task<int()>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/packaged_task/packaged_task) being `explicit`. From [cppreference/explicit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit):

> Specifies that a constructor or conversion function (since C++11)or deduction guide (since C++17) is explicit, that is, it cannot be used for implicit conversions and copy-initialization.

The constructor is a perfect match (template argument `T` matches anything) but its not a viable user defined conversion sequence (and there are also no other viable conversions from the lambda to `std::packaged_task<int()>`). It fails for the same reason this does:

```
struct foo { };

struct bar {
    explicit bar(foo){}
};

int main() {
    foo f;
    bar b = f;
}
```

[Live](https://godbolt.org/z/8r1cK7nGo):

```
<source>:9:13: error: conversion from 'foo' to non-scalar type 'bar' requested
    9 |     bar b = f;
      |             ^
```

While, removing the `explicit` (https://godbolt.org/z/cPx97zx1e) or using `bar b(f);` (https://godbolt.org/z/WMYrb18P8) is not an error.

Note that things do not change when replacing constructor above with a templated one ([the error](https://godbolt.org/z/Gzj6hT5W9) / [witout explicit](https://godbolt.org/z/MsxjvKET4) / [calling the constructor explicitly](https://godbolt.org/z/cd7TEjf4r) ).

Comment: I guess I don't understand what the difference between bar b(f) and bar b = f is in this case. How is one different from the other?

Comment: @glades, that's what `explicit` does: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit

Comment: @glades `bar b= f;` requires a conversion to be avialble, there is but you would need to call it explicitly, as in `bar b = bar(f);`. With `bar b(f)` you are calling the constructor explicitly

Comment: @ChrisMM Ah I see... But on the other hand why do I even need to convert something, there's a constructor `template <class F> explicit packaged_task( F&& f );` that takes anything?

Comment: @glades its in the section you quote "Otherwise, if T is a class type, and the cv-unqualified version of the type of other is not T or derived from T, or if T is non-class type, but the type of other is a class type, user-defined conversion sequences that can convert from the type of other to T ...". The lambda is not a `std::packaged_task<int()>`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I don't understand. Couldn't I deduce `template <class F> explicit packaged_task( F&& f );` as F = main::lambda_xy and have a perfectly fitting constructor?

Comment: @glades the constructor does fit perfectly, but it is explicit. It is not considered for implicit conversions.

Comment: @glades maybe I should have used this as examples: https://godbolt.org/z/cbrqc4GrE, without explicit: https://godbolt.org/z/ojnjYKGzv calling it explicitly: https://godbolt.org/z/5vfv4Td6s

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number So you're saying that even though there exists a constructor that matches our type (lambda) perfectly, it is not considered due to it being a _converting_ constructor AND specified explicit?

Comment: @glades yes, as Chris mentioned, thats basically what `explicit` means https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit

Comment: " Specifies that a constructor or conversion function (since C++11)or deduction guide (since C++17) is explicit, that is, it cannot be used for implicit conversions and copy-initialization."

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Thanks. They should add a note that this is also true for templated constructors.

Comment: @glades "a constructor" is general enough, it covers non-template and templated constructors